# Are the 1-parameters subgroups of $SO(3)$ closed?

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, lie-groups, matrix-exponential

I'm trying to solve the following question

> **Question:** Prove that all $1$-parameters subgroup of $SO(3)$ are closed. Does this statement holds for $SO(n),$ $n>3$?

---

### Some comments

The $1$-parameters subgroups of $SO(n)$ are the groups

$$P_A := \{e^{tA};\ A \in M_n(\mathbb{R})\ \text{and}\ A+A^T = 0\}. $$

Since $SO(n)$ is compact the exponential map is surjective, and the map $\mathbb{R}\to P_A\ (t\mapsto e^{tA})$ is an   <s>isomorphism of groups (it is easy to see that $0$ is the unique element of the kernel, sinse $e^B = \text{Id}$ $\Leftrightarrow B =0$)</s> 
 homomorphism of groups.

<s>Being honest I can't believe that $P_A$ is closed when $n=3$, the fact of $P_A \cong \mathbb{R}$ as a group makes me have no idea of what is going on, once $P_A$ closed would imply $P_A$ compact.</s>

EDIT: After Reuns' help I realised that I wroted thing that does not make any sense.

---

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you sure that $\mathbb R \rightarrow P_A$ is an isomorphism?  What would make more sense to me is to have $P_A \cong \mathbb R/\mathbb Z$, since closed subsets of compacts are compact as you said.

Comment: @D_S I do think so, because $e^{tA}=\text{Id}$, implies $tA=0$, have I made a mistake?

Comment: I'd say $P_A \cong \{ \lambda m + \Bbb{Z}^n, m \in \Bbb{Z}\} \subset \Bbb{R^n/ Z^n}$  where $2i\pi \lambda_j$ are the eigenvalues of $A$, and $P_A \cong \Bbb{R/Z}$ iff the ratios between those eigenvalues are rational. Otherwise $P_A \cong \Bbb{R}$ and it isn't closed. $e^{tA}=\text{Id}$ implies $Q\frac{tA}{2i\pi}Q^{-1}$ is diagonal with integer entries for some $Q$.

Comment: @reuns But if all entries of $A$ and $Q$ are real numbers, then $\frac{t}{2\pi i} Q A Q^{-1}$ is an imaginary matrix. If $A$ is a real matrix then $e^A = I \Rightarrow\  A=0$, isn't it?

Comment: You should diagonalize $\pmatrix{1/\sqrt{2} & 1/\sqrt{2} \\ 1/\sqrt{2}&-1/\sqrt{2}}\in SO(2)$ and compute the one parameter subgroup it belongs to

Comment: You are right $$\text {exp}\left (\pmatrix { 0 & 2\pi  \\ -2\pi &0} \right) = \text {Id}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** One can compute the $1$-parameter subgroups rather explicitly.

Consider the one-parameter subgroup $t \mapsto \exp t A$ determined by the any $n \times n$ skew-symmetric (and hence diagonalizable) matrix $A$. By skew-symmetry its eigenvalues are imaginary and (since $A$ is real) the set of eigenvalues is closed under conjugation.

For $n = 3$, the eigenvalues are $+ \lambda i, -\lambda i, 0$ for some $\lambda \in \Bbb R$. Diagonalizing $A$ then gives
$$A = P D P^{-1}, \qquad D := \operatorname{diag}(\lambda i, -\lambda i, 0) ,$$
for some matrix $P$.

> Then, $$\exp t A = \exp t (P D P^{-1}) = P \exp (tD) P^{-1} = P \operatorname{diag}(\exp(\lambda i t),\exp(-\lambda i t),1) P^{-1}. $$ Is $t \mapsto \exp t A$ periodic?

For $n \geq 4$ the situation is qualitatively different, and the case $n = 4$ illustrates the general phenomenon. The eigenvalues are $\pm \lambda i, \pm \mu i$ for some $\lambda, \mu \in \Bbb R$, and so $D$ in the above statement is replaced by $$D := \operatorname{diag}(\lambda i, -\lambda i, \mu i, -\mu i) .$$

> Proceeding as before gives $$\exp tA = P \operatorname{diag}(\exp (\lambda i t), \exp(-\lambda i t), \exp(\mu i t), \exp(-\mu i t)) P^{-1}.$$ Under what condition on $\lambda, \mu$ is $t \mapsto \exp t A$ periodic? Show that when this map is not periodic, the image of $\exp tA$ is dense in $SO(4)$ but does not contain $-I$.

Comment: Amazing idea, using it when $SO(n)$ $n>3$, it is clear that we can find a  skew-symmetric matrix $A$  such that $$\varphi: \mathbb{R}\to P_A$$ $$t \mapsto e^{tA}, $$ is a isomorphism (to construct this map we just 
 need to find some  skew-symmetric with eigenvalues  $i \lambda_1$ and $i \lambda_2$ such that $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ are l.i. under $\mathbb{Q}$ ). Is it clear that $P_A$ is not closed? because maybe $P_A$ is not embedded in $SO(n)$. So say that $\mathbb{R}\cong P_A$ as topological spaces (anlysing $P_A$ with subspace topology) seems a little complicated.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right. And yes, in that case $P_A$ is not closed: For example, for $n = 4$ one can find a sequence of points in $P_A$ that converges to $-I$, but this point itself cannot be in $P_A$, and thus $P_A$ is not closed. In particular, the subspace topology on $P_A$ is not the same as the topology induced by declaring $\varphi$ to be a homeomorphism. Cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_flow_on_the_torus#Irrational_winding_of_a_torus

Comment: The idea of finding a sequence that converges to $ -I $ is completely superb

Comment: Then we need to show for any admissible $D$ there exists $A \in M_n(\Bbb{R}), A^\top = -A$ such that $A = P D P^{-1}$, using $Q = \pmatrix{1 & i \\ 1 & -i},QQ^* = 2I$ and $P = \pmatrix{Q & & \\ & Q & \\ & & \ldots}$ @MatheusManzatto